# Make KDE Plasma Task switcher show only on primary display

Tags: kde, kde-plasma-5, task-switching

Is there a way to get the task-switcher to only display itself on the primary monitor.

My case is that I have a small secondary monitor that I only use for terminals, so I my focus expects the task-switcher to appear on my primary monitor. However, if the windows on the 2. monitor has focus, the task switcher will show up there, and it really bugs me.

My current settings:

[image: My current settings]

Comment: three screens here, really annoying to look fot the switcher every time :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading a similar question and the response from a KWin maintainer I think we can safely say it is not possible (even though the question was not precissely the same).

Extract from [comment on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/6y7bh0/is_it_possible_to_view_the_task_switcher_popup_on/):

> No, that is not possible.
> /KWin maintainer
>
> Yes alt+tab is part of KWin (called TabBox there). The only way to extend it would be from within kwin project. But that's not an easy task to be totally honest. The code is designed for only one view, changing that is something I would say is close to impossible due to the way how the tabbox is "special". E.g. it intercepts key events, evaluates them and then forwards them to the view. If there are multiple views, who knows what will happen?

Answer (score 0):

I just hit this snag as well, with my vertical (1080x1920) secondary monitor. While not exactly what you're asking for, the following tickbox will make the alt+tab switcher appear on the screen that your mouse pointer is currently on:

System settings -> Window Management -> Multiscreen behavior: Active screen follows mouse

For my purposes, I find this an acceptable workaround.